# data.table grouping separately on numeric and text variables

Tags: r, join, data.table, lapply

I'm trying to simplify this `data.table` two-stage process which acts on both numeric and character variables. E.g. - take the first element of `textvar` and `sum` each of the numeric variables. Consider this small example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(grpvar=letters[c(1,1,2)], textvar=c("one","two","one"),
                 numvar=1:3, othernum=2:4)
dt
#   grpvar textvar numvar othernum
#1:      a     one      1        2
#2:      a     two      2        3
#3:      b     one      3        4
```

Now my first thought was to nest `.SD` to drop the one variable out of the `lapply` call, but I thought that was a bit complicated:

```
dt[, c(textvar=textvar[1], .SD[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=-c("textvar")]), by=grpvar]
#   grpvar textvar numvar othernum
#1:      a     one      3        5
#2:      b     one      3        4
```

Then I thought maybe I could do each grouping separately and join them, but that seems even worse:

```
dt[, .(textvar=textvar[1]), by=grpvar][ 
  dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=grpvar, .SDcols=-c("textvar")], on="grpvar" 
]
#   grpvar textvar numvar othernum
#1:      a     one      3        5
#2:      b     one      3        4
```

Is there a simpler construction that would get around the nesting of `.SD` or the joining? I feel like I'm overlooking something elementary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `j`-argument in *data.table* is (deliberately) quite flexible. All we need to remember is that:

> As long as `j` returns a *list*, each element of the list will become a column in the resulting data.table.

Using the fact that `c(list, list)` is a `list`, we can construct the expression as follows:

```
dt[, c(textvar = textvar[1L], lapply(.SD, sum)), # select/compute all cols necessary
      .SDcols = numvar:othernum,                 # provide .SD's columns 
      by = grpvar]                               # group by 'grpvar'
#    grpvar textvar numvar othernum
# 1:      a     one      3        5
# 2:      b     one      3        4
```

Here, I've not wrapped the first expression with `list()` since `textvar[1L]` returns a length=1 vector.. i.e., `identical(c(1, list(2, 3)), c(list(1), list(2,3)))` is `TRUE`.

Note that this is only possible from `v1.9.7`. The bug was just recently fixed in the current development version.

Comment: I'll have to take your word for the moment as I am on 1.9.6 and not in a position to upgrade until later on, but thanks for the quick response. So 1.9.7 will avoid the "object 'textvar' not found" error?

Comment: @thelatemail, yes. This was a long standing (and annoying) error that we managed to finally fix in this release.. [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495).

Comment: @thelatemail if you are on windows there is pkg binaries available on appveyor so Rtools is not needed as you don't need to build from source, just grabbing zip from appveyor. Just letting you know if that was the case to stay on 1.9.6.