# R data.table returns duplicate rows when specifying selected columns differently

Tags: r, data.table

I would expect both ways to return the very same `data.table`, do you know why are the results different?

```
tmp <- data.table(a=c(1:9), b=c(11:19), c=c(rep(7:9, 3)),d=c(rep(4:6, 3)))

> tmp[, lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, x = a, w = b), by=c('c', 'd')]
   c d        a        b
1: 7 4 4.428571 4.428571
2: 8 5 5.400000 5.400000
3: 9 6 6.375000 6.375000
> 
> tmp[, .(lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, x = a, w = b)), by=c('c', 'd')]
   c d       V1
1: 7 4 4.428571
2: 7 4 4.428571
3: 8 5      5.4
4: 8 5      5.4
5: 9 6    6.375
6: 9 6    6.375
```

Comment: I think the answer to this other recent question covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39260984 "As long as `j` returns a list, each element of the list will become a column in the resulting data.table." In the first case, you have a list `L` with one element per column in .SD; and in the second, you wrap it like `list(L)`, which only has one element.

Comment: @akrun Dunno. That quote is relevant, but the misunderstanding it came from is different. It could be closed as a typo, I suppose, but it's valuable enough to keep around, so yeah, maybe dupe it.

Comment: The real question is why would you expect that.

Comment: FYI `.()` is alias to `list()`

Comment: @DavidArenburg When working with a single non-list column, including/omitting `.()` doesn't matter, for convenience: `d = data.table(a = 1); d[, 2, by=a]; d[, .(2), by=a]; d[, b := 2]; d[, b := .(2)]` I can see how that could lead to confusion. It also leads to some confusion around making list columns like `.(.(x))` and similar.

Comment: @DavidArenburg This could be a well know fact for data.table users, but for someone who just starts off its not quite intuitive why does that work the way it does. I used this tutorial: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf which has a number of examples for working with multiple columns, but not when there are multiple columns after grouping by.

Comment: @jangorecki This is all i needed to know, thanks.